# TypeError: Object � by Node.JS buffer.readUInt8LE();

Tags: node.js

could someone tell me why I got the TypeError shown below? Thanks.

Kernel: 
Linux Orion 3.16.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 17 21:54:13 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Node: v0.10.32

npm: 2.1.3

net: 1.0.2

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '192.168.1.1';
var PORT = 26862;

net.createServer(function(sock) {   

     sock.on('data', function(buffer) {

         console.log(buffer.length);
         // >> 50

         var commandTag = buffer.readUInt16LE(0);
         var sequenceNumber = buffer.readUInt8LE(2);
         var reserved = buffer.readUInt8LE(3);
         var len = buffer.readUInt32LE(4);
         var connectionId = undefined;
     });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```

> /OpenIPTServer/IptCommand.js:16
>
> var sequenceNumber = buffer.readUInt8LE(2);
>
> ```
>                        ^
> ```
>
> TypeError: Object �

David

Answer (score 1):

There is no `readUInt8LE()` because endianness does not factor in for just a single byte. It's just `readUInt8()`. However bytes in a Buffer are unsigned by default, so you don't need to use a method for that, just use bracket notation: `buffer[2]`.